# "Decorating" your office

Tags: professionalism, office-layout

So, I know that decorating (i.e. bringing in little knick knacks) one's office is "rite of passage" so to speak. Though what is the norm or standard usually allowed? Do you bring stuff in secretly or a little pronounced? Also, how long should you wait to decorate when starting a new job?

Answer (score 7):

What's acceptable varies tremendously from company to company, and even location to location within a company. Ask your manager, and look at what the norm is among your co-workers. Try not to embarass yourself; try to keep it polite; think twice before displaying anything controversial.

Comment: Well dang that kills my "Deh Furher IS Watching" poster. Yeah, I just don't want people to think they are distractions. I just want to add a few desk "toys" since I see and talk to people regularly.

Comment: If others have fidget widgets on their desks, you're probably fine with something similar. If in doubt, ask your mangler. [Sic]

Answer (score 3):

It's not as obvious as some people think so I'll add it here - **magnets on the side of PCs/CPUs are a no-no**. IT Support staff all have war stories surrounding this!

Answer (score 2):

As soon as I knew where my permanent position (desk, bench etc,.) was I would have a framed picture of the wife and kids on my desk, usually my own coffee mug, and cleaned and customised my space.

Thoroughly cleaning and setting up my workspace is my first task I set myself, before I even do any work at it, I've never asked permission.

If you mean things like calendars etc,. just bring them in but make sure they're not going to offend anyone, so don't bring in the Playboy calendar or anything like that.

Comment: Really?  Does that perturb your manager?

Comment: Playboy calendar? I don't know, I just used it as an example, it's not something I would bring to work. As for the rest, I rarely ask permission to do things not directly related to my work, I can always apologise if I breach some unspoken protocol, but it never happened that I recall. It's harmless enough.